# iOS 9 hairline between UINavigationController and UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift2, uinavigationbar, ios9, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` under which a `UISearchController` is placed programmatically.

```
searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 242/255.0, green: 82/255.0, blue: 46/255.0, alpha: 0.4)
searchController.searchBar.translucent = false
searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 0
```

I setup my `UISearchController` like above.
I set the `UINavigationBar` its design globally like this:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 242/255.0, green: 82/255.0, blue: 46/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarPosition: .Any, barMetrics: .Default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().layer.shadowRadius = 0
UINavigationBar.appearance().layer.shadowOpacity = 0
UINavigationBar.appearance().layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0)
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "JosefinSans-SemiBold", size: 18)!
]
```

It should've removed that 1px hairline border, but it didn't. I read that it's because of the shadow image, but I can't seem to remove that 1px hairline.
Who can help me out?

Comment: I have the same problem. Tag me please if you find a solution!

Comment: @AnnabelleSykes Answer is below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 0
```

with this:

```
searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 242/255.0, green: 82/255.0, blue: 46/255.0, alpha: 1).CGColor
searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

Comment: Yeah, fixed it! Thank you!